# JQuery.get() halting setinterval after first request

Tags: jquery, setinterval

I'm using the following code to keep track of how long a user is watching a video. It seems that the setinterval halts after the first GET request:

```
setInterval(function(){jQuery.get("some_url.php");}, 500);
```

Any idea why? Thanks!

Comment: Any errors in console?

Comment: look for ajax long pooling

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yup. It will surely hang there, I'd be surprised if it didn't crash.

What you're doing is you're creating a new request every *half second* So by 20 seconds you will have created 40 requests.
It has to send a request, wait for it to respond, process it and while it is doing it, it has to create another request.. The requests are therefore piling on and browser has no more memory to process.

```
1000 milliseconds = 1 second
```

So, lengthen the milliseconds and it should run fine.